# How to point two UINavigationControllers to one view controller using storyboards?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios6, uistoryboard

I am attempting to connect two UINavigationControllers, representing different tabs in a tab bar application, towards a single UICollectionViewController. The collection view controller will be populated by different data based on which navigation controller is the parent. When both navigation controllers are connected, navigating to the second tab displays a black screen and the viewWillAppear() code in the controller for the collection view does not fire. When navigating to the first tab, everything fires and is displayed correctly with data populated.

The storyboard setup looks like this:
[image: storyboard screenshot]

The navigation controllers are connected to the collection view controller as seen here:
[image: segue connections]

If I disconnect *either* one of the two navigation controller connections, the remaining connection to the collection view works and collection items are displayed as expected.
[image: storyboard with one connection removed]

Is this the correct way to reuse the collection view? Is there something missing from how I am connecting the two navigation controllers with segues to the single UICollectionView?

Answer (score 0):

I see this is almost a year old, so I'm not sure if you found an answer or not, but I thought I'd help answer if needed. Without knowing too much of your project, can I ask why you want a tabBarController to point both of its view controllers to the same one? Makes me wonder why tabBarController is necessary.

Setting up a test project, I witnessed the same you did. The only thing I can think of is that when a view controller is instantiated via the Storyboard, it creates an instance of it and is stored in the tabBarController's viewControllers[i] property, which the other tab may not have access to in the hierarchy. It would be best to just copy the view controller object from the Storyboard and paste it onto another area of the storyboard, and have the tabBarController instantiate a new instance of the same view controller object. That way, in your viewDidLoad method, you can tell what the selectedIndex is, and know how to load data, alter interface, etc. Copying/pasting the Storyboard view controller should keep intact any outlets/actions you've set up.

Hope that helps...

Comment: The reasoning is that while the view controller's layout and logic were identical across the tabs, the data presented was different. I have not revisited this project so there may be a better way to do this now.